# Downloading and importing Google Cloud Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform

I'm on their github page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python

Their first command is `pip install --upgrade google-cloud`

this gives me:

```
Collecting google-cloud
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-cloud (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for google-cloud
```

I downloaded their SDK and which installed their google cloud SDK and I did gcloud init, but I can't seem to have their python library imported into mine. Starting python and typing:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
```

gives me an error that it doesn't exist as a module... This is all from their github so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the team is trying to transition from `gcloud` to `google-cloud` which is still somewhere incomplete.

All you need to do is install `gcloud` using `pip` and you should be fine.

Pro Tip: `python -m pip install --upgrade gcloud` using this command will install it for your python version.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have installed `gcloud` on your system then run the commands like this:

**First:** `gcloud components update` in your terminal.

**then:** `pip install google-cloud`

**And for the import error:**

I had a similar problem. Adding "--ignore-installed" to my pip command made it work for me.

This might be a bug in pip - see this page for more details: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2751